# mapping over higher dimensional numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a 1d array `a` and want to map a function `f` over each element, I could do

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> a = np.arange(5)
>>> def f(x):
...     return 3*x + x**2 #whatever 
>>> np.fromiter(map(f,a),float)
array([ 0.,  4., 10., 18., 28.])
```

I'd like to do something analogous with more complex arrays. One example calculation is this: compose paired 3x3 arrays with matrix multiplication

```
>>> a = np.arange(5*2*3**2).reshape(5,2,3,3)
>>> def f(x):
...     return np.matmul(x[0],x[1])
# is there a smarter way? 
>>> np.array([f(x) for x in a])
array([[[   42,    45,    48],
        [  150,   162,   174],
        [  258,   279,   300]],

       [[ 1716,  1773,  1830],
        [ 1986,  2052,  2118],
        [ 2256,  2331,  2406]],

       [[ 5334,  5445,  5556],
        [ 5766,  5886,  6006],
        [ 6198,  6327,  6456]],

       [[10896, 11061, 11226],
        [11490, 11664, 11838],
        [12084, 12267, 12450]],

       [[18402, 18621, 18840],
        [19158, 19386, 19614],
        [19914, 20151, 20388]]])
```

Another example calculation would be transform every vector in an array of vectors by matrix multiplication

```
>>> a = np.arange(3*5).reshape(5,3)
>>> def f(x):
...     M = np.arange(3*3).reshape(3,3)
...     return np.dot(M,x)
>>> np.array([f(x) for x in a])
array([[  5,  14,  23],
       [ 14,  50,  86],
       [ 23,  86, 149],
       [ 32, 122, 212],
       [ 41, 158, 275]])
```

Is there a nice way to do such computations with an `np.fromiter` like approach? What is the most pythonic way to do these operations with `numpy`? Is there an approach which handles every example problem here as `np.specialnumpything(map(f,a))`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `fromiter` instead of just broadcasting?  I mean `3*a + a**2`, `np.dot(a[:,0], a[:,1])` and `np.dot(M, a)` all work perfectly fine

Comment: I'm not tied to `fromiter`. I just saw that as the generalization I need. That's not actually how I'd do the first example. How would you approach the second example?

Comment: My second implementation is wrong.  You'd want `a[:, 0] @ a[:, 1]`

Comment: I was just finding that. That's exactly what I need @DanielF. I just have not learned to use `@` yet. Thanks! submit as answer if you want the rep. I did not know how to broadcast matrix multiplication

Comment: In `numpy` iterative approaches (including `map`) are slow, and should be avoided unless there isn't way of using the compiled whole-array methods, including broadcasting.

Comment: There's an important distinction between applying a function to each element of an array, and applying the function to subarrays (slices) along one or another axis.  If working with every element, the problem isn't inherently multidimensional; with `ravel` and `reshape` you can cast it as a 1d problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just as easily implemented with broadcasting.  Namely:

```
a = np.arange(5)
a*3 + a**2

array([ 0,  4, 10, 18, 28])

a = np.arange(5*2*3**2).reshape(5,2,3,3)

a[:, 0] @ a[:, 1]

array([[[   42,    45,    48],
        [  150,   162,   174],
        [  258,   279,   300]],

       [[ 1716,  1773,  1830],
        [ 1986,  2052,  2118],
        [ 2256,  2331,  2406]],

       [[ 5334,  5445,  5556],
        [ 5766,  5886,  6006],
        [ 6198,  6327,  6456]],

       [[10896, 11061, 11226],
        [11490, 11664, 11838],
        [12084, 12267, 12450]],

       [[18402, 18621, 18840],
        [19158, 19386, 19614],
        [19914, 20151, 20388]]])


a = np.arange(3*5).reshape(5,3)
M = np.arange(3*3).reshape(3,3)

M.dot(a.T).T

array([[  5,  14,  23],
       [ 14,  50,  86],
       [ 23,  86, 149],
       [ 32, 122, 212],
       [ 41, 158, 275]])

np.einsum('kj, ij -> ik', M, a)

array([[  5,  14,  23],
       [ 14,  50,  86],
       [ 23,  86, 149],
       [ 32, 122, 212],
       [ 41, 158, 275]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the builtin `numpy.nditer`, which could be what you're looking for:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html

from the examples:

```
>>> a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
>>> a
>>> array([[0, 1, 2],
           [3, 4, 5]])
>>> with np.nditer(a, op_flags=['readwrite']) as it:
    ...    for x in it:
    ...        x[...] = 2 * x
    ...
>>> a
    array([[ 0,  2,  4],
           [ 6,  8, 10]])
```

Comment: I don't recommend using `nditer` unless you need some special property, or intend to move on to `cython`.  When used in Python code it's slower than other iteration methods, and much slower than non-iterative methods (such as `a *= 2` in your example).

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks for that info :)